# project oxford text not printing correctly

Tags: node.js, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using project oxfords modules and I trying to print out the text in the image
when i print response it looks like this. My guess is the text is in the 'lines'. How do i print that?
[image]

```
client3 = new oxford.Client('api key')
client3.vision.ocr({
 path: './words.jpg',
 language: 'en',
}).then(function (response) {
 console.log(response);
}).catch(function (err) {
 console.log(err);
});
```

probably a simple fix I just cant figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a sample JSON [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc).

Basically, `lines` is an array of an object consisting of a `boundingBox` and `words`.  `words`, in turn, is an array of object consisting of a `boundingBox` and `text`.

So for example, you could do something like this:

```
for (i=0; i<response.regions.length; i++) {
  region = response.regions[i];
  for (j=0; j<region.lines.length; j++) {
    line = region.lines[j];
    words = [];
    for (k=0; k<line.words.length; k++) {
      words.push(line.words[k].text);
    }
    console.log(words.join(' '));
  }
}
```